# XAMLparse exceoption error

Tags: c#, object-oriented-database

Please I need assistance... My program which i am using c# and post relational database but i keep getting this error it says the xaml parse exception error was unhandled , please where am i going wrong the code is

```
<Window x:Class="zooSystemWorking.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="442" Width="884" Loaded="Window_Loaded" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Background="#F2C1D42D" Height="405">
        <Image Height="139" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/ZooLogo.jpg" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" />
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF0A0A09" BorderThickness="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,145,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" CornerRadius="10" Background="#95005202">
            <Button Content="Add Animal" Height="23" Name="addAnimal" Click="addAnimal_Click" Width="87" Background="#95005202" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#95005202" Foreground="#F2C1D42D" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF101010" BorderThickness="1" Height="25" Name="border2" Width="93" Margin="6,185,764,195" CornerRadius="10" Background="#95005202">
            <Button Content="View Animal" Height="23" Name="viewAnimal" Click="viewAnimal_Click" Width="86" Background="#95005202" Foreground="#F2C1D42D" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF0A0A09" BorderThickness="1" Height="25" Name="border3" Width="93" Margin="6,227,764,153" CornerRadius="10" Background="#95005202">
            <Button Content="Update Animal" Height="23" Name="updateAnimal" Click="updateAnimal_Click" Width="84" Background="#95005202" Foreground="#F2C1D42D" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF0D0D0C" BorderThickness="1" Height="25" Name="border4" Width="93" Margin="6,268,764,112" CornerRadius="10" Background="#95005202">
            <Button Content="Archive Animal" Height="23" Name="archiveAnimal" Click="archiveAnimal_Click" Width="84" Background="#95005202" BorderBrush="#95005202" Padding="0" Foreground="#F2C1D42D" />
        </Border>
        <ContentControl Height="326" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,-1,0,0" Name="contentArea" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="758" />
        <Image Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,333,0,0" Name="image2" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/grass.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
        <Image Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,333,0,0" Name="image3" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/grass.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
        <Image Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,333,0,0" Name="image4" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/grass.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
        <Image Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="429,333,0,0" Name="image5" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/grass.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
        <Image Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="572,333,0,0" Name="image6" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/grass.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
        <Image Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="717,333,0,0" Name="image7" Source="/zooSystemWorking;component/Images/grass.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
        <Border Background="#95005202" BorderBrush="#FF0D0D0C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Height="25" Margin="6,305,763,75" Name="border5" Width="93">
            <Button Background="#95005202" BorderBrush="#95005202" Click="reportGen_Click" Content="Report" Foreground="#F2C1D42D" Height="23" Name="reportGen" Padding="0" Width="84" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: yes i have a object database @GrantWInney do you think that maybe the database might be wrong?

Comment: I typed ctrl+alt+E and it says this "The assembly with display name 'MatisseNet' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1."

Comment: What's also important, but perhaps not the issue, is the `Name` attribute. In wpf and silverlight you should use `x:Name` instead of `Name`.

Comment: Have you checked the signatures on all your event handlers?

Comment: I checked your xaml and there is nothing really wrong with it. I copied the xaml from your post to make sure there are no invisible characters present. You should provide more information for us to be able to help you. Where does the exception occur, does it have an inner exception? Please provide the necessary details for us to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes it has an inner exeption and it says this "The assembly with display name 'MatisseNet' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MatisseNet, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cb3cc33d88ea9b76' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" i have one table in the object database called Fish, do you think thats why the problem is coming up?